# Скачать данные из сети с помощью NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, сеть

Воспользовался асинхронным запросом, но не знаю как  быть дальше. Если я хочу , чтобы данные не выводились с помощью NSLog, а, к примеру записывались в переменную класса, как это сделать?

```
  -(void)loadHTMLDataFromURL:(NSString*) url
{
    NSURL *transformedUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:transformedUrl];
    NSOperationQueue *queue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:queue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data, NSError *connectError)
     {
         if([data length]>0)
         {
             NSString *html=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@",html);
         }

     } ];

}
```

Comment: Может быть вам для начала нужно почитать про ООП?

Comment: У меня есть переменная класса, к примеру NSData *testData  - но внутри блока я пробовал ее использовать, и при выходе в этой переменной ничего нет. Я просто совсем не знаком с блоками, в этом видимо и проблема.

Comment: А в лог данные выводятся?

Comment: выводятся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А где вы потом пытаетесь использовать переменную test?
Вы понимаете, что у вас асинхронный запрос?
То есть вот такая конструкция не прокатит:

```
[self loadHTMLDataFromURL:@"http://ваш урл"];
NSLog(@"%@", test); // (null)!
```

Как вариант, можно добавить блок в параметр метода, и вызывать его в блоке запроса.

```
-(void)loadHTMLDataFromURL:(NSString*)url complete:(void(^)(NSData *data))block
....
block(data);
```

Использование:

```
[self loadHTMLDataFromURL:@"http://google.com" complete:^(NSData *data) {
   test = data;
   NSLog(@"%@", data);

}];
```